# I Want to change navbar font-size

Tags: navbar, font-size

How i can change navbar font-size?

[Image <--](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0iJm.png)

Link: http://infinitefun20.blogspot.gr

Comment: You must add some minimum code so others can evaluate it and help you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

since all elements are inside `<a>` tag inside .navbar-inverse to change to font size you could do

```
.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .nav > li > a {
 font-size:10px;
}
```